# Use between_time() on MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex as follows:

```
                             col  col  col  col ...
tstp                    pkt                                                   
2016-04-14 04:05:32.321 0    ...  ...  ...  ...
                        25   ...  ...  ...  ...
2016-04-14 04:05:32.322 1    ...  ...  ...  ...   
                        26   ...  ...  ...  ...  
2016-04-14 04:05:32.374 2    ...  ...  ...  ...
...
```

Once I determine `beg` and `end`, I'd like to use the `df[].between_time(beg,end)` to grab the relevant rows from the DataFrame. Only problem is, `.between_time(beg,end)` seems to work only on a DateTimeIndex:

```
*** TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex
```

Or is the more appropriate way to do this via `xs()`?

```
df.xs(slice(beg,end),level='tstp')
```

Comment: What's wrong with `df.xs(slice(beg,end),level='tstp')`?

Comment: The only alternative I see would be to make `pkt` into a regular column, apply `between_time`, them move `pkt` back to the index.

Comment: @IanS I guess nothing is wrong with it.

Comment: Then that's certainly the best way right now. Apparently as of pandas 18.1, multiindex [will support datetime indexing](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#partial-string-indexing-on-datetimeindex-when-part-of-a-multiindex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get the result you want:

## Option 1

**Probably the best is to use** `DataFrame.loc` **to index directly into the** `MutliIndex`:

```
df.loc[beg:end]
```

## Option 2

If you need to use `between_time`, you could `unstack` the second level of the index out, then use `between_time` and finally `stack` the second level back:

```
df.unstack().between_time(beg,end).stack()
```

## Option 3

As IanS mentioned, `xs` will give you a similar result:

```
df.xs(slice(beg,end),level='tstp')
```

## Conclusion

The first option seems like the cleanest and also the fastest:

```
>>> timeit df.loc[beg:end]
1000 loops, best of 3: 317 µs per loop

>>> timeit df.unstack().between_time(beg,end).stack()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.35 ms per loop

>>> timeit df.xs(slice(beg,end),level='tstp')
1000 loops, best of 3: 632 µs per loop
```

Example Jupyter notebook [here](https://gist.github.com/adebar/d2ca73f44125722a0bedebf07c346479).

Comment: Thanks for doing the profiling; I'm working on a large dataset where performance is an issue.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a link to a Jupyter notebook I used to test the options. Have a look at that if you want to dig around a bit more yourself.

Comment: Note that `.loc[beg:end]` doesn't seem to work with arbitrary ranges. `beg` and `end` must be actual elements in the index. In that situation, `.xs` will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the apply method:

```
df = df.groupby(["pkt"]).apply(
    lambda x: x.loc[x.name, :].between_time(bgn, end)
)
```